# creating upload interface to picasa web for google app engine python

Tags: google-app-engine, picasa

Is there any sample application or code example for uploading image to picasa using GAE python. How to insert picasa uploaded image url into datastore then. Is there any effective way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the [gdata-python-client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) library.  It works on AppEngine and wraps the Picasa Web API, amongst others.